# Magento 2: Adding quote and order attribute using patch data

Tags: magento2.3, patch-data

Can we add custom quote and order attribute/field using patch data in Magento 2.3.x ? If yes then how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to add a custom Quote Attribute (programatically) in Magento 2.* using patch:

```
namespace Firewalls\ZipCheck\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

use Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup;

class SelectedShippingMethods implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $quoteSetup;

    public function __construct(
        QuoteSetup $quoteSetup
    )
    {
        $this->quoteSetup = $quoteSetup;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->quoteSetup->addAttribute(
            'quote_item',
            'custom_attribute_code',
            [
                'type'=> Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable'=>true,
                'comment'=>'Selected Shipping Methods'
            ]
        );
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }


}
```